# Python: How to replace negative values with "0" in a matrix?

Tags: python-3.x, replace, floating-point

Let's say I have a  matrix

```
x = [[0.708, 0.000, -0.070],
[-0.004, 0.561, -0.088 ],
[ 0.001, -0.001 -0.023]]
```

I want to replace all the negative values if it begins `-0.0` with 0.

Is there any way to do it python. Since my matrix is really big, it also need to be computationally efficient ?

Comment: if the value is -1.23 you don't want to replace it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest solution I would suggest is using numpy for handling any matrix operations so you won't have to reimplement the wheel. Maybe it would be worth looking into numpy masking operations, like [masked_where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ma.masked_where.html)

I'm not saying this is the most efficient solution, really don't know what you consider big matrix and what sort of efficiency you need, I would probably try several approaches, and compare them using profiler and decide which is best for you.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> x = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, -99, 5])
>>> c = numpy.ma.masked_where(x < 0, x, copy=False)
>>> c
masked_array(data = [1 2 3 -- 5],
             mask = [False False False  True False],
       fill_value = 999999)

>>> x2 = c.filled(0)
>>> x2
array([1, 2, 3, 0, 5])
```

Comment: My data is numpy array. I want to replace all the elements starts with "- 0.0" not  " -0.5". But your answer helps to replace only "-99" , which is negative integer.

Comment: What I posted is just an example, you can have the array filled with floats and it'll still work. And you can specify any interval in masked_where or use masked_inside which is a shortcut like this `c = numpy.ma.masked_inside(x, 0, -0.1, copy=False)`